# React Navbar problem (Sticky : Top) not working on 2 navbar on a single screen

Tags: reactjs, components, react-bootstrap

importing two navbar in a website. both are sticky, but when i am scrolling down navbar 1 is not getting sticky. and if i used the position : top then only one Navbar shows, not the other one is shown on the screen.

Code:

```
      return (
        <>
            <Navbar bg="light" sticky='top'>
                <Container>
                    <Navbar.Brand>Update — $7,500 tax credit is anticipated to be reduced for Model 3 on April 18. Take delivery now. Learn More</Navbar.Brand>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>

            <Navbar style={{background:'transparent'}} bg="dark" variant="dark" sticky='top'>
                <Container>
                    <Teslaicon />
                    {/* <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand> */}
                    <Nav className="me-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="home">Model S</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#features">Model 3</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Model X</Nav.Link>   <Nav.Link href="home">Model S</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#features">Model Y</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </>)
}
```